# Excel formula - Absolute reference to cell

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In my excel 2010 worksheet, I have entered a formula `=+H8+N8*AA7` where AA7 is a permanent number where as H20 & N20 will change.

But if I copy this formula to the below row, it pastes as `=+H8+N8*AA9`, the next row `=+H8+N8*AA11` and then again to `=+H8+N8*AA13` etc.

In this formula, I always need to multiply the H & N column by AA7. But AA7 keeps on changing. Please give the reason & a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the $ sign to force the cell reference (AKA absolute cell reference).

If want to keep both cell and column type $AA$7 (regardless of where you drag the formula too).

EG `=+H8+N8*$AA$7`

You may also need to use the [Indirect](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/indirect.htm) keyword.

Further examples of the [absolute cell reference](http://www.awardsites.com/tutorials/excel/cell_ref-01.htm).

Answer (score 1):

You also have the option of naming the cell.

The box where the AA7 is written when you select the field is editable. So you can give it a context-friendly name, and use that in your calculations.

IE. name the field `"interest"` and use `=H8+N8*interest`

Comment: Can you explain how to name the field please?

Comment: See 1-2-3 steps here: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/444/excellabels.png/
just select the field, type the name + enter, and use your new label everywhere. To move a label to another field, you must cut and paste the label-field to its new position.