# How to not change certain values when dragging in Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have a formula like below

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE('Code Repository'!B2, "/browse/master/", C4, ";", 'Code Repository'!B3, "$", D4), "Link")
```

I don't want `'Code Repository'!B2` and `'Code Repository'!B3` to change when I drag the formula into multiple rows. But they are incrementing along with `C` and `D` values in the formula. For example like below

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE('Code Repository'!B20, "/browse/master/", C20, ";", 'Code Repository'!B21, "$", D20), "Link")
```

I don't want to this to happen. What I want is below

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE('Code Repository'!B2, "/browse/master/", C20, ";", 'Code Repository'!B3, "$", D20), "Link")
```

The `B2` and `B3` are constants. How do I achieve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel formula - Absolute reference to cell](https://superuser.com/questions/459918/excel-formula-absolute-reference-to-cell)

Answer (score 1):

Should use `$` before row number to keep it constant. The query will be below

```
 =HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE('Code Repository'!B$2, "/browse/master/", C4, ";", 'Code Repository'!B$3, "$", D4), "Link")
```